# MySQL local network query issue

Tags: mysql, vb6

I work with a software developed in Visual Basic 6 which MySQL is the database. Our application works in a local network and always worked fine, but just one costumer is having an issue. The question is when the consultant does something in our application the MySQL database takes too much time to search or stops to work, but when I'm on the machine that is installed MySQL (5.5) it is working.
I already have tried some tips, changing my.ini file lines, grant all command, reinstallation and etc.

Maybe the problem could be the local network? Any advice?

I have to apologize for my english if something don't look right,

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved my problem, It was easier than I thought.
I had to go in Performance Options from Windows and change the Virtual Memory, just this.